# LabelEncoder won't encode strings?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to encode the non-numeric columns of a pandas df to numeric values. I'm using

```
df = df.fillna('0')
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
df_train = df[msk]
df_test = df[~msk]
columns_to_encode = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number]).columns
encoder_dict = {col: LabelEncoder() for col in columns_to_encode }
df_train_enc = df_train
df_test_enc = df_test
for col in columns_to_encode:
    encoder_dict[col].fit_transform(df_train_enc[col])
```

This, however, throws an error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`. What am I missing here? I thought LabelEncoder should be able to transform strings to numerics...

Comment: You might have `nan` values in your data, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43956705/4121573

Comment: I don't, see updated post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) works on string labels without an issue, so, in case you have mixed types in your data (due to missing values, for example), you can use:

```
for col in columns_to_encode:
    encoder_dict[col].fit_transform(df_train_enc[col].astype(str))
```

Comment: Did you try `astype(str)`?

Comment: Yes, that helped, will accept in 7 mins. Thank you!